# KeyboardWillHide called while KeyboardWillShow is still animating

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Currently I have a view animating with the keyboard when the keyboard shows or hides. I have added a gesture recognizer so that when the user taps off the keyboard it disappears.

The issue I have run into is where if the user taps away to lower the keyboard while the keyboard is appearing, the keyboard disappears and my view is not lowered. I have actually noticed that the view moves even higher for whatever reason.

Here are my keyboard listener methods:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
            responseNode.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height-tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height
            tableNode.view.contentInset.bottom += keyboardSize.height-tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height
        }
    }
}
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
            responseNode.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height-tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height
            tableNode.view.contentInset.bottom -= keyboardSize.height-tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I hide the keyboard:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If possible, try using autolayout, I guess changing the frame could be unpredictable in this case.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
 }

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    text.resignFirstResponder()

    return true

}
```

Comment: This will hide the keyboard